# running a function containing "value_counts" on multiple variables of a dataframe at once

Tags: python, function

I want to call a function on all variables in a dataframe. My function contains '**value_counts**' attribute and returns an error "'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'value_counts'". what should be the right approach?

[My dataframe looks like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxkFw.png)

```
def absolute_and_relative_freq(variable, flag):
    global  ax, ax1 
    # Dataframe of absolute and relative frequency for Var & Event
    absolute_frequency = variable.value_counts()
    relative_frequency = (round(variable.value_counts()/len(tppf)*100, 2))
    ct = pd.crosstab(variable,flag)
    event_rate = round((ct[1]/absolute_frequency)*100,2)
    # Was multiplied by 100 and rounded to 2 decimal points for percentage.
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Absolute Frequency':absolute_frequency, 'Relative Frequency(%)':relative_frequency,'event_count':ct[1], 'event' : event_rate})
    df.sort_values('Absolute Frequency',axis = 0, ascending = False,inplace = True )
    print('Absolute & Relative Frequency of',variable.name,':')
    display(df)
    fig_size = (12,8)
    font_size = 12
    title_size = 18   
    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 10))
    ax2 = ax1.twinx()
    df['Relative Frequency(%)'].plot(title = ' %s' %variable.name,figsize = fig_size,kind='bar', color='b', ax=ax1,label = 'pct_total')
    df['event'].plot(kind='line',color='r', marker='s', ax=ax2,label = 'pct_event')
    ax1.legend(loc =0)
    ax2.legend(loc =2)
    ax1.set_ylabel('Relative Frequency(%)',fontsize =font_size)
    #ax2.set_ylabel('Event Rate(%)',fontsize =font_size)
    #ax1.yaxis.tick_left()
    #ax2.yaxis.tick_left()
    #risky = 
    #plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

[I should be getting such table for each variable and graphs.][2]

I tried running a for loop:

```
list1 = ['POL_STATUS', 'INSURANCE_OBJ', 'SECTOR', 'PLAN_ID']
for l in list1 :
    absolute_and_relative_freq(l, tppf.UR_FLAG_NEW)
```

Comment: This code will give you an error: `NameError: name 'absolute_and_relative_freq' is not defined`. Please post the actual code you're running.

Comment: That was wrongly written. Corrected it now.

Answer (score 0):

value_counts() can only be used on a Series

```
def absolute_and_relative_freq(df,variable, flag):
     absolute_frequency = df[variable].value_counts()
```